# Pasting a list next to another list

Tags: notepad++

Is there a way in notepad++ to paste a list of items next to a pre-existing list? Or something else that can help me with this?

so ...

item 1
item 2
item 3

item a
item b
item c

has to become:

item 1 item a
item 2 item b
item 3 item c

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Secret is to select the right hand column text using Alt key (in column mode).

1/ Hold Alt and select the items a,b,c by starting from column 1 and drag down and out until the 3 alpha item lines are selected.

2/ Copy this to clipboard.

3/ Add space at end of items 1,2,3

4/ Move cursor to end of line 1 ("item 1 ") and paste in.

You should be done.